# jquery - How to properly copy data from div to new window dynamically

Tags: jquery, printing

I have a problem. Im trying to create a very simple print preview that when the user clicks the `Print Preview` button it will open a new window and copies the data I wanted. There are some elements like the checkbox that I don't want to include but Im able to do it successfully. My problem is when the new window is loaded the original div is also altered. Like the checkboxes are removed in the original div and the `Print` button also appears.

I want my original div which is `divData` to remain the same. I don't have problem with the new window.

Btw my jquery codes are below:

```
        $("#btnPrintPreview").click (function () {
            var printContents = new $("#divData");
            var myWindow = window.open("", "popup","width=1000,height=600,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes," +  
                "toolbar=no,directories=no,location=no,menubar=no,status=no,left=0,top=0");
            var doc = myWindow.document;
            doc.open();
            $(printContents).find(".tCheckboxes").remove();
            var button = "<input type='button' id='btnPrint' value='Print' style='float: right;' onclick='window.print();'/>";
            $(printContents).append($(button));
            doc.write($(printContents).html());
            doc.close();
        });
```

To see my demo here is the link http://jsfiddle.net/dU7et/.

PS: Please check the main div after clicking the `Print Preview`.

Please help me....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this to do what you are wanting change the following line to:

```
// Before:
var printContents = new $("#divData");
// After:
var printContents = $("#divData").clone();
```

See http://api.jquery.com/clone/ for further reference.

Comment: @EricTung  What if I want to add css to this... I want different css for `printContents` and actual css for original `#divData`

Comment: @aks, The return type of .clone() is a selected object instance from jQuery. If you created a scoped set of styles (eg: ".print-style div { some: css; } .print-style p { more: css; }") you could simply add a class to the new entity, ex: printContents.addClass("print-style");